# Extending a function that maps the basis of $V_1$ to $V_2$ to the linear map $f:V_1 → V_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations

Let V1,V2 be vector spaces over the same field F, and let B be a basis of
V1.

Can we extend any function

$φ : B → V_2$
to a linear map $f : V_1 → V_2$?

If yes, how? If such an extension exists, is it unique?

So I know this is true for surjective functions, because since $B$ is a basis of $V_1$, it is also a spanning and linearly independent set of $V_1$. This means that for every vector $x \in$ $V_1$ we can write x as a unique (well except for reordering)  linear combination of distinct vectors in $B$. Now the issue I'm having is that I need to prove that $range(f)=V_2$ but I'm unsure how to do this without the assumption that the function is surjective? Can anyone help me?

Comment: In short, yes you can always **uniquely** extend such a function into a linear map, but the result may not be surjective (e.g. if $\varphi$ maps all basis vectors to $0$, then $f$ must map all vectors to $0$, which is not typically surjective). How important is it to have $\operatorname{Range}(f) = V_2$? Can we not just have $V_2$ be the codomain, instead of the range?

Comment: $f$ always exists, but it might not be injective and might not be surjective.

Comment: It will work.  If $B$ is a basis, just extend linearly.  The extension is unique.  Surjectivity is irrelevant.